# replace notepad with notepad++ --> The Process does not own any identity

Tags: windows, windows-10, notepad++, notepad, debugger

A time ago, I set notepad++ as a debugger for notepad, in order to automatically open it instead of the default editor. See [this](https://winaero.com/blog/replace-notepad-notepad-plus-plus/) for example.

I did this by just `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\notepad.exe\Debugger` to `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" -notepadStyleCmdline -z`.

Unfortunatly, this does not work any more. I get a weird error massage saying the following: [image: Der Prozess besitzt keine Paketidentität]

My system is german, so the message is `The process does not own any packet identity`.

I use an insider build of Windows 10 Home:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19013.1122]
```

I can include more information if needed.

Comment: Did you do any research before asking? When searching for "The process does not own any package identity." I can see some solved threads already, for example [this](https://github.com/microsoft/DesktopBridgeToUWP-Samples/issues/60)

Comment: Yes but I didn't find anything helpful.

Comment: For example, the linked article says that the app may require to be properly installed. Not a portable version.

Comment: As far as I know, I have installed the non-portable version.

Comment: What about reinstalling N++ using the installer just to make sure everything is initialized correctly by the installer? If that does not work, could you try the same technique for Notepad replacement with yet another editor, e.g. SynWrite? To check if your issue is reladed with current N++ installation or any N++ installation or any other editor?

Comment: Currently, I'm on my mobile phone but I will try it later.